# memory address translation in hypervisor guest os

Tags: linux, memory, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtual-memory

Assume there is a code like this.

```
MOV [0x1234], EAX (intel assembly)
```

let's say that CPU wants to process this instruction.
and let's assume there is no hypervisor.
we are just using normal x86 CPU(protected mode) in linux environment.

now, what I understand is that
since 0x1234 is a virtual address, this needs to be translated
into physical address.(let's skip segmentation part)

CPU just pass this address(0x1234) to MMU hardware.
MMU walks the page table and access the memory contents using physical address.

am I correct?

now let's assume there is hypervisor and this code
is running from guest OS.

what happens exactly??

I know that hypervisor provides another layer of page table.
but I don't understand how exactly this works.

if the guest code "MOV [0x1234], EAX" is executed
in real CPU. the virtual address 0x1234 will be translated by
real hardware MMU. so I think this instruction has to be
rewritten(0x1234 should be replaced to another address
before the code is executed), or trapped to hypervisor...

am I wrong?
if I am wrong, please fix my understanding...

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering your first question: yes you are. That's basically how virtual memory works.

Now, let's see what's happen when an hypervisor is running between the MMU and a guest OS. For performance sake, an hypervisor (weither it's a *type 1* or *type 2*) would try to avoid trapping at each guest OS memory access. The idea is to *let* the guest OS managing the MMU. I will elaborate with possible implementations, one for x86 and one for PowerPC.

On x86, from the [Intel's manual 3B](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

> 27.3.2 Guest & Host Physical Address Spaces
>
> Memory virtualization provides guest software with contiguous guest physical
>   address space starting zero and extending to the maximum address supported by
>   the guest virtual processor’s physical address width. The VMM utilizes guest physical
>   to host physical address mapping to locate all or portions of the guest physical
>   address space in host memory. The VMM is responsible for the policies and algorithms
>   for this mapping which may take into account the host system physical
>   memory map and the virtualized physical memory map exposed to a guest by the
>   VMM.

The VMM knows the current `PDBR` base address of the VM (the `PDBR` is hold in the `CR3` register), since an access to `CR3` will cause a VM_EXIT. The VMM will be able to maintain the real page directory on the behalf of the guest OS. I mean when the guest OS modifies its page directory to map logical address A to physical address B, the VMM traps on this, and instead of mapping A to B, it maps A to C. Thus any further access to A won't cause a #PF, it will be flawlessly routed to C through the MMU. The sad part on this approach is that the guest believes it has mapped A to B, but actually A is mapped to C, thus the VMM has to maintain a virtual page directory in case that the guest would read where it has previously mapped A. The VMM traps on this read access, and instead of saying A is mapped to B, it returns to the guest that A is mapped to C.

> 27.3.3 Virtualizing Virtual Memory by Brute Force
>
> A simple-minded way to do this would be to ensure that all guest attempts to access
>   address-translation hardware trap to the VMM where such operations can be properly
>   emulated. It must ensure that accesses to page directories and page tables also get
>   trapped. This may be done by protecting these in-memory structures with conventional
>   page-based protection. The VMM can do this because it can locate the page
>   directory because its base address is in CR3 and the VMM receives control on any
>   change to CR3; it can locate the page tables because their base addresses are in the
>   page directory.

On PowerPC, you don't have an hardware table-walk of a page directory as Intel's. Each modification of the TLB is induced by an instruction, usually from the kernel memory manager. Here again, a straightforward idea is to trap on each guest access to the TLB (setting up things to cause a VM exit when the guest execute a `tlbwe` instruction for instance; note: `tlbwe` writes an entry into the TLB). Once inside the VMM, the hypervisor decodes the trapping instruction, and emulates its behaviour, but instead of mapping A to B, it maps A to C, directly into the TLB. Again the VMM has to maintain a *virtual TLB* in case the guest OS wants to check what's in the TLB, and returns what it believes to have put in the TLB earlier.

To conclude, although some hardware features help in virtualizing the guest physical memory, **it's generally up to the VMM to manage the effective guest-physical to host-physical memory mapping**.